# How to preserve braces in result

Tags: equation-solving, functions, sets

I have a result from equation, for example

> p={{0<=x<=1/5||x==9/10},{0<=x<=1/5||x==9/10}}

and using

> Cases[p, z_?NumericQ -> z, Infinity]

I get

> {0,1/5,9/10,0,1/5,9/10}

But I would like to get a set, where the braces from the result are preserved. Like this:

> {{0,1/5,9/10},{0,1/5,9/10}}

Any ideas how could I do it?
Thank you for any advices.

Comment: `Cases[#, z_?NumericQ -> z, Infinity] & /@ p`

Comment: {Cases[p, z_?NumericQ -> z, Infinity]}